# Why do we allow interface to be used as a type in Java?

Tags: java, interface, queue

For example, I often see something like this:

```
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
```

I totally understand the point that by declaring it as a type of Queue, any class that implements Queue interface can be used to instantiate the object.

What bothers me is that often I see something like

**q.size()**

to get the size of the Queue.

This compiles and works fine, but to me, doing something like this defeats the concept of "interface", because size() is a method in LinkedList class.

Essentially we need to be aware of what class was used to instantiate the queue object. If we later decided to use a different class to instantiate this queue object, then we may run into trouble

e.g. if we decide **NOT** to use LinkedList class and decide to use to some other class to instantiate the queue object, **we need to make sure that the new class also has the method size(), otherwise we will need to change it.**

Note: I am using size() method just **as an example.**  Potentially, any method that LinkedList has can be called on the queue object right? What would we do if we later decided to use some other class to instantiate the queue object? We need to make sure that this new class also has the same method, right? This seems to be defeating the purpose of interface. **If we declare a variable as an interface type, we should only be using the methods specific to that interface.**

Am I missing some points here?

Comment: actually that is the concept of the interface. You want to get the `size` of the queue, nontheless of it´s implementation

Comment: `size()` *is* a method on `Queue` (by merit of `Queue` extending `Collection`, which defines the method). If it was not, you could not do `q.size()` (without downcasting).

Comment: "If we declare a variable as an interface type, we should only be using the methods specific to interface.". Yes. And that's what you are doing here.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 3):

Any `Queue` implementation would have the `size()` method, since `size()` is a method of the `Collection` interface, which the `Queue` interface extends. Therefore, `size()` belongs to the `Queue` interface indirectly.

Comment: I used size() as an example. 
potentially, we could use any method that LinkedList class has, right?

In that case, what do we do if we later decide to use some other class to instantiate the queue object? wouldn't it defeat the purpose of "interface"?

Comment: @ShotaHino No. When you have a `Queue` variable, you can only use methods of the `Queue` interface. In order to use methods of `LinkedList` that are not part of the `Queue` interface, you'll have to cast your variable to `LinkedList`, which will only work if that variable happens to refer to an instance of `LinkedList`. In order for your code to work with any implementation of `Queue`, you should avoid doing that.

Comment: @ShotaHino what you are defining as defeating the purpose is actually the purpose of the interface. You want to use the behavior of a `List` as adding, deleting and so on. You don´t care how the `List` does actually behave internally, how the concrete class did implement it. The interface defines a common construct shared with all siblings. How each sibling does behave, when it did get implemented doesn´t matter for you.

Comment: @Eran Oh, I see. That clears up my confusion. Thank you